# Network (via ethernet) does not work after sleep mode

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I recently installed Debian 10.6 on my desktop computer, and discovered that I have a problem with my ethernet network connection after waking the computer from sleep mode. Specifically, after waking the computer from sleep mode, I have no ethernet network connection. After rebooting the computer, the connection is restored. My Linux kernel version is 4.19.0-11-amd64. Any ideas how to solve this strange problem?

Following the suggestion from A.B, here is the output from `lspci -k | grep -A3 Ethernet`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8071 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 88E8071 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
    Kernel modules: sky2
03:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
```

I don't know if it helps, but I have now also added some relevant lines from running `dmesg` below:
After waking from sleep:

```
[ 7544.632643] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 7544.935093] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[ 7544.937339] sky2 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: enabling interface
[ 7544.937528] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[ 7547.437266] do_IRQ: 2.34 No irq handler for vector
```

After rebooting:

```
[   19.698910] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   19.701050] sky2 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: enabling interface
[   19.701183] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   22.187327] sky2 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both
[   22.187359] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[   53.492928] fuse init (API version 7.27)
[   60.534172] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Comment: It could also involve the specific NIC hardware and its driver. You should provide the NIC model and driver. Perhaps from `lspci -k|grep -A3 Ethernet`, or if the device is named eth0 (please adapt) `ethtool -i eth0`.

Comment: Please use ethtool instead. You missed the additional lines (-A3) from lspci giving also the driver in use

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the suggestion! I have added the output from lspci -k | grep Ethernet. For some strange reason I cannot run ethtool ("command does not exist"), even though I just installed it!

Comment: run ethtool as root (or with sudo)

Comment: @A.B I tried, but it's not working. I run "apt-get install ethtool" and I get ethtool is already the newest version (1:4.19-1). Then I try (still as su) "ethtool -i eth0" and I get "bash: ethtool: command not found".

Comment: @A.B I will try to reboot (since I haven't rebooted after installing ethtool) and see if it works then.

Comment: I can see various fixes related to suspend for various *pc models* using sky2. Check: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/?h=linux-5.8.y&qt=grep&q=sky2 . Anyway if I were you I'd try if using a newer kernel would fix the problem. Using [backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) you could install linux-image-5.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64-unsigned (probably requires UEFI not in secure mode). Beside this I don't have any better idea.

Comment: @A.B Ok, thanks for your suggestions. For some strange reason I still cannot run ethtool!

Comment: check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029620/ubuntu-18-04-lts-sky2-ethernet-stops-working-after-system-resume-from-suspend#comment1956841_1094045

Comment: @A.B Thanks for pointing this out! Do you know what he means by grub file? Is this GRUB as in the bootloader?

Comment: @A.B Fantastic, it works! Thanks for the help. Do you want to write an answer, should I do it, or should we leave it entirely?

Comment: Please write the answer. Just give references (not me, but the askubuntu question and possibly other links)

Comment: @A.B Ok, done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the problem in my case had to do with the following line in the output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 7547.437266] do_IRQ: 2.34 No irq handler for vector
```

This problem is addressed in the following post on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029620/ubuntu-18-04-lts-sky2-ethernet-stops-working-after-system-resume-from-suspend#comment1956841_1094045. Many thanks to user A.B for pointing out this post to me!

I did the following to solve the problem:

- Add the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash sky2.disable_msi=1"` to the file /etc/default/grub
- Run the command `update-grub`. Note: I had to do `su - root` rather than just `su` in order to be able to run `update-grub`.
- Reboot the computer.

Comment: I've started getting this problem (with a `dmesg` line of the form: `__common_interrupt: 1.33 No irq handler for vector`) since upgrading from Devuan 3 "Chimaera" with a 5.10 kernel to Devuan 4 "Daedalus" with a 6.1 one. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=287759 gives some useful details which matched mine: system goes to sleep and when it wakes up the wired network does not work and the workaround was - as root - `service networking stop; rmmod sky2; modprobe sky2; service networking start`. I am just trying adding `disable_msi=1` to a (new file) `/etc/modules-load.d/sjy2.conf`...

Comment: I should have mentioned that the file (`sky2.conf`, there was a typo in the previous comment and I didn't spot it in time to correct) would be needed for that sequence of four superuser commands to have worked without `disable_msi=1` being given as an additional argument to the `modprobe` one! Anyhow this seems to fix things. 8-)

Comment: This kml thread gives more insight as well: https://lore.kernel.org/all/aba1c363-92de-66d7-4aac-b555f398e70a@alvarezp.org/  particularly examining the output from `cat /proc/interrupts | grep eth` to see if the option has taken effect and the interrupt is of type `IO-APIC` (OK) or `PCI_MSI` (BAD).